# MySQL Left Joins: Select everything from one table, but only matching value in second table with criteria

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables. I want to select everything from one table and the matching row from the second table - that matches a criteria.

So `tblConfig_Group` contains a list of groups.

```
|ID | groupCode | 
|1  | A         |
|2  | B         |
|3  | C         |
|4  | D         |
```

And `tblConfig_CustomerGroup` contains a list of groups and customers in that those groups.

```
|ID | groupCode | customerID |
|1  | A         | 74         |
|2  | B         | 74         |
|3  | A         | 235        |
|4  | C         | 74         |
```

It should only display rows from the second table where there is a match 
AND criteria (`customerID` = 74)

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**

```
|ID | groupCode | customerID |
|1  | A         | 74         |
|2  | B         | 74         |
|3  | C         | 74         |
|4  | D         |            |
```

I've tried a number of queries but it doesn't seem to work for me...

**SQL Query 1:**

```
SELECT g.groupCode,  cg.customerID FROM tblConfig_Group g 
LEFT JOIN tblConfig_CustomerGroup cg ON g.groupCode = cg.groupCode  
WHERE cg.customerID = '74'
```

**ACTUAL RESULTS:** rows 1, 2 & 3.

```
| groupCode | customerID |
| A         | 74         |
| B         | 74         |
| A         | 74         |
```

**SQL Query 2:**

```
SELECT g.groupCode,  cg.customerID FROM tblConfig_Group g 
left outer join tblConfig_CustomerGroup cg on g.groupCode = cg.groupCode   
WHERE cg.customerID = '74' 
UNION  
SELECT g.groupCode, cg.customerID 
FROM tblConfig_Group g 
right outer join tblConfig_CustomerGroup cg on g.groupCode = cg.groupCode
```

**ACTUAL RESULTS:** rows 1, 2 & 3 + customer 235

```
| groupCode | customerID |
| A         | 74         |
| B         | 74         |
| A         | 74         |
| A         | 235        |
```

Comment: why in expected result you expect `id=3` and `groupCode=A` in 3rd row?

Comment: When you use `LEFT JOIN`, the criteria on the second table should be put into the `ON` clause, because putting it in the `WHERE` clause filters out the rows where `cg.customerID` is `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Alex, you are quite right, i had corrected it to C but it didn't save.

Comment: Barmar, you mean replace the WHERE with and AND. Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  g.id,
  g.groupCode, 
  cg.customerID 
FROM tblConfig_Group g 
LEFT JOIN tblConfig_CustomerGroup cg 
ON g.groupCode = cg.groupCode 
  AND cg.customerID = '74';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is essentially correct but just missing a tiny bit to include the nulls

```
SELECT g.groupCode, cg.customerID FROM tblConfig_Group g
LEFT JOIN tblConfig_CustomerGroup cg 
ON g.groupCode = cg.groupCode WHERE cg.customerID = '74'
OR cg.customerID IS NULL;
```

Another solution is

```
SELECT g.groupCode, cg.customerID FROM tblConfig_Group g
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT * FROM tblConfig_CustomerGroup 
    WHERE customerID = '74') AS cg 
ON g.groupCode = cg.groupCode
```

Comment: Tested both of these queries and they work too. 
thanks e4c5!

Comment: glad to have helped